# FluentNHibernate automapping "no persister for"

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I'm using the most recent version of Sharp Architecture, and having problems when I call SaveOrUpdate on a repository.  I'm always getting the MappingException with No persister for:  error.  I haven't changed much from the default Sharp Architecture, and I'm pointing towards the dll that contains my entities.  Has anyone run into this problem?  It was working before with manual mappings before I switched to using Sharp Architecture.
Thanks!

Here is the generation function I'm using.  TestEntity is in another project that is referenced from the data project.  If I add a ClassMap for TestEntity, it finds the mapping.

```
public AutoPersistenceModel Generate()
{
    return AutoMap.AssemblyOf<TestEntity>(new AutomappingConfiguration())
        .Conventions.Setup(GetConventions())
        .IgnoreBase<Entity>()
        .IgnoreBase(typeof(EntityWithTypedId<>))
        .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModelGenerator>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message indicates that you are trying to save unmapped entity. Sharp Architecture has an extension method that allows you to save all the mappings as XML files. Try to use it and check what entities have really being mapped.

Comment: Do you mean the WriteMappingsTo method?  When I call that after loading the assembly with my entities, I don't get any files in the output directory.

Comment: When I add ClassMap<> mappings it seems to pick up the mappings, and I get a SQL error instead.  For some reason it's just not working with the Automapping.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Would you share your solution?I have the same situation creating model and viewmodel classes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess my automapping configuration was filtering it out - once I derived my TestEntity from Entity, the automapper picked it up.